# How do I make a JSlider background transparent? or How do I properly overlay JComponents in JLayeredPane?

Tags: java, swing, transparent, jslider, jlayeredpane

I am trying to overlay a JSlider on top of a JProgressBar. I am using a JLayeredPane to hold the two components. I am adding the JProgressBar to the JLayeredPane and then adding the JSlider. So far, I have attempted to make the JSlider transparent by setting opaque to false and overriding the paintComponent method. What I end up with is that the slider handle is the only part that becomes transparent while the background stays opaque. It is possible that I am not using the JLayeredPane correctly, but my tests with JLabels seemed to work. How do I get the background of the JSlider to be transparent?

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider()
{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
    {
        java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, (float) 0.5));

        super.paintComponent(g2);
    }

};
```

Thank you all for your help. Through your examples, I have discovered that my issue is with the JLayeredPane that I am using. I recognize that the JSlider background can be made transparent, however, I still cannot get the components on layers beneath to show through. This is my example:

```
public class SliderTest extends JFrame
{

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                SliderTest frame = new SliderTest();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public SliderTest()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();

    panel.add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setValue(50);
    layeredPane.add(progressBar);
    layeredPane.setLayer(progressBar, 0);

    JSlider slider = new JSlider()
    {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();

            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    };
    layeredPane.setLayer(slider, 1);
    slider.setOpaque(false);

    // layeredPane.setLayer(slider, 1);
    layeredPane.add(slider, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: My JSlider works just fine.Show us the code to find out the fault.

Comment: Using `setOpaque(false)` on the JSlider works like a charm for me. No need to override anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will depend upon what it is you want to achieve.  By default `JSlider` is transparent.

What's important here is that the opaque property MUST be `false`, otherwise the repaint manager will not paint behind the components...

[image]

- Top slider, transparent background (blue), opaque control
- Middle slider, transparent background (green), transparent control
- Bottom slider, normal `JSlider`

  public class TestSlider {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new TestSlider();
  }

  public TestSlider() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
              } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
              }

              JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
              frame.add(new TestPane());
              frame.pack();
              frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
              frame.setVisible(true);
          }

      });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

      public TestPane() {
          setBackground(Color.RED);

          setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
          GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
          gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
          gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

          add(new TransparentBackgroundSlider(), gbc);
          add(new TransparentSlider(), gbc);
          add(new JSlider(), gbc);

      }

  }

  public class TransparentBackgroundSlider extends JSlider {

      public TransparentBackgroundSlider() {
          // Important, we taking over the filling of the
          // component...
          setOpaque(false);
          setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      }

      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
          g2d.setColor(getBackground());
          g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
          g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
          g2d.dispose();

          super.paintComponent(g);
      }

  }

  public class TransparentSlider extends JSlider {

      public TransparentSlider() {
          // Important, we taking over the filling of the
          // component...
          setOpaque(false);
          setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      }

      @Override
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
          g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
          super.paint(g2d);
          g2d.dispose();
      }

      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          // We need this because we've taken over the painting of the component
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
          g2d.setColor(getBackground());
          g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
          g2d.dispose();

          super.paintComponent(g);
      }

  }
  ```

  }

**Update with layer example**

[image]

```
public class TestSlider {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSlider();
    }

    public TestSlider() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JLayeredPane {

        private JProgressBar pb;
        private JSlider slider;

        public TestPane() {

            pb = new JProgressBar();
            slider = new JSlider();

            add(pb, new Integer(0));
            add(slider, new Integer(1));

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = pb.getPreferredSize();
            size.height *= 4;
            size.width = Math.max(size.width, slider.getPreferredSize().width);
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            Dimension size = pb.getPreferredSize();

            int x = 10;
            int y = (getHeight() - size.height) / 2;

            pb.setLocation(x, y);
            size.width = getWidth() - 21;
            pb.setSize(size);

            size = slider.getPreferredSize();
            x = (getWidth() - size.width) / 2;
            y = (getHeight() - size.height) / 2;
            slider.setBounds(x, y, size.width, size.height);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: +1, nice example. Just as a tiny improvements, you could replace all your `gridx/gridy` with a single `gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;` (which basically lays out all components vertically).

Comment: Thank you. This proves to me that the JSlider can be made transparent. However, I am still having difficulty overlaying a JSlider on top of a JProgressBar using the JLayeredPane. Do you know how to use JLayeredPane to do this?

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the result I wanted using that. Why do you have to override the layout and assign positions manually? If possible I would prefer using a BorderLayout and setting the JLayeredPane in the center so that all resizing is done automatically.

Comment: @JustinWiseman To my understanding, JLayeredPane does not support layout managers as it has it own for mangling the layers, hence the reason I did my positioning manually